# iOS AudioKit Hight Pass Filter

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audiokit

I am trying to detect pitch from iOS microphone with AudioKit, and here is the code

```
    init() {
        guard let input = engine.input else {
            fatalError()
        }

        mic = input

        filter = HighPassFilter(mic, cutoffFrequency: 200, resonance: 40)
        silence = Fader(filter, gain: 0)
        tracker = PitchTap(silence) { pitch , amp in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(pitch[0], amp[0])
                self.update(pitch[0], amp[0])
            }
        }
        engine.output = filter
    }

    func start() {
        recordFrequency = []
        do {
            try engine.start()
            tracker.start()
        } catch let err {
            Log(err)
        }
    }
```

Because there's always some detect (frequency 20 to 200) when I don't make sounds,
I add a high pass filter to filt the sound lower than 40 dB and 200 frequencies,
But it seems not work, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have some connection point issues. Try putting the tracker before you make the signal silent:

```
    filter = HighPassFilter(mic, cutoffFrequency: 200, resonance: 40)
    tracker = PitchTap(filter) { pitch , amp in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(pitch[0], amp[0])
            self.update(pitch[0], amp[0])
        }
    }
    silence = Fader(tracker, gain: 0)
    engine.output = filter
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it shows  "Argument type 'PitchTap?' does not conform to expected type 'Node'" at line 7 "Fader(tracker, gain: 0)", I tried to change it to "        silence = Fader(filter, gain: 0)
engine.output = filter", but it seems there's still have some detect (frequency 20 to 200) when I don't make sounds, Is my understanding of the filter wrong?

Comment: here is the result without filter "68.16507 0.036659416
119.37795 0.03836245
40.35377 0.03510648
39.63465 0.034352873
19.66473 0.03518843
40.085865 0.036239482
41.060604 0.036827385
57.55008 0.03376852
60.191628 0.0360921
120.31841 0.03350037
119.31205 0.03380238"

Comment: here is the result with filter "201.63512 0.27862206
199.87314 0.38526902
200.97998 0.29951045
199.40402 0.2626813
197.7091 0.1736537
204.10585 0.19162786
40.259094 0.20084965
39.73761 0.116548724
205.8079 0.14439781
199.77483 0.12242793
199.62943 0.14312659
200.65292 0.20651947
199.87216 0.32285377
197.07616 0.16549863"